# how to move from one main listview fragment to other different listview fragments by clicking main listview's list items

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to make call from my main listview Fragment to another differnt listview fragments by clickig different items on main list view.

For that i have written following code:

My main listview fragment **ShopFragment.java**:
(from this list items i want to call another fragments by clicking on different items)

```
package fragments.h.safmical;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import safmical.h.R;

/**
 * Created by hadvani on 4/13/2017.
 */

public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop,container,false);
        String[] list1={"x","y","z"};
        ListView listView= (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.mainlist);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listviewadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list1);
        listView.setAdapter(listviewadapter);
        FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();
        listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0){

                       fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new ListOneFragment()).commit();
                }
                if(position==1){
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new ListTwoFragment()).commit();
                }
                if(position==2){fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new ListThreeFragment()).commit();}
            }
        });
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

xml file of main listview fragment **fragment_shop.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e6e6fa">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainlist"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**ListOneFragment.java**:

```
package fragments.h.safmical;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import safmical.h.R;

/**
 * Created by hadvani on 4/14/2017.
 */

public class ListOneFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listone, container, false);
        String[] list1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.list1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listviewadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);
        listView.setAdapter(listviewadapter);
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

**fragment_listone.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list1">

</ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Same way i have implemented **ListTwoFragment.java** , **ListThreeFragment.java** , **fragment_listtwo.xml** and **fragment_listthree.xml**.

but its not working. Gradle build shows following error:

```
Error:(30, 17) error: no suitable method found for setOnClickListener(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>)
method View.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to OnClickListener)
method AdapterView.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to OnClickListener)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Should i make any correction or is there any differnet method to do this?
**Please help me to solve this**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
listView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

to

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

What's happening is that it's trying `OnClickListener` instead of `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: yeh,i have changed it and then i declare fm as final .So errors solved.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `OnClickListener` for `ListView`. Use `OnItemClickListener` instead, documented here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)

Comment: yeh,i have changed it and then i declare fm as final .So errors solved.Thanks